# Android Background Services

Tags: android

I am creating an "ToDoTask" application in android. I have created feature of adding task and deleting task with a particular date. I have saved these task list into database. Now I want to add a feature according to which if any task is in incomplete status than a notification will be generated for all the tasks which are saved with today's date. How can I accomplished this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Register a PendingIntent with AlarmManager that will run say once a day. Start off an IntentService when the PendingIntent is fired. in this Service, you can check if any of your tasks are incomplete for the day. If so, use NotificationManager to trigger a notification.